# Xamarin Forms - Google Drive

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am stuck trying to connect to Google Drive in Xamarin.Forms (iOS & Android). I cant seem to find any examples on how it should be done. I tried something with Xamarin.Auth OAuth2Authenticator and OAuth2Request but I dont know how to continue or even if this is the right way?

This is what I have so far.

```
private static readonly string[] Scopes = { DriveService.Scope.DriveAppdata };
    private const string ApplicationName = "MyDriveApp";
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Page> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator(
           "clientId", "clientSecret",
           Scopes[0], new Uri("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth"), new Uri("http://localhost"),
           new Uri("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"));
        auth.Completed += Auth_Completed;
        var activity = Context as Activity;
        activity.StartActivity(auth.GetUI(activity));


    }
private void Auth_Completed(object sender, AuthenticatorCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                _store.Save(e.Account,"google");
                //
            }

        }`
```

Comment: Maybe this post can help you: https://plus.google.com/u/0/+StephenWylie/posts/CD3L8zcJg5Z I am not sure if you are going to find something Xamarin.Forms or Xamarin.Android specific so -what you gone do?- Go native

Comment: Thank you! I will look into it.

Comment: have you done the integration?

Comment: Where is this code? Which class?